# MobileConnect export short/long code list

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect

Is there a way to get the short/long/alpha code list from the MobileConnect on MarketingCloud?

I see the list is there but need to go into each code to get more details... Is there a way to get the full list?

Answer (score 1):

Which information exactly would you like to retrieve? The '[SMS Message Summary](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_re_sms_message_summary.htm&type=5)' and '[SMS Message Detail](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_re_sms_message_detail_report.htm&type=5)' reports provide useful information within the shortcode.

Comment: Only all the codes available and which countries are using them, also if those are shared or not

Comment: That information is available in the Administration tab and cannot be exported. If you need more information just open a ticket to support.

Comment: That's what I did. Thanks